# For timescaledb how to calculate the network interface traffic rate （derivative function similar to elasticserach）

Tags: elasticsearch, derivative, timescaledb

For timescaledb how to calculate the network interface traffic  rate （derivative function similar to elasticserach）

I've been using elasticsearch for time series data analysis, but now I'm trying to migrate to timescaledb and I'm having trouble figuring out which function to use to solve the rate calculation problem

```
  |@timestamp                   | name  | in_octets     | out_octets
  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 23:03:06.000 | ether1 | 3,463,588,268 | 2,372,374,994

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 23:02:58.000 | ether1 | 3,462,781,744 | 2,371,162,827

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 23:01:01.000 | ether1 | 3,452,914,965 | 2,356,385,005

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 23:00:58.000 | ether1 | 3,452,576,204 | 2,356,016,021

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:58:57.000 | ether1 | 3,441,936,733 | 2,340,373,010

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:58:49.000 | ether1 | 3,441,241,534 | 2,339,326,251

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:57:09.000 | ether1 | 3,432,536,413 | 2,326,334,762

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:57:02.000 | ether1 | 3,431,944,892 | 2,325,566,509

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:55:09.000 | ether1 | 3,422,644,761 | 2,311,544,431

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:54:59.000 | ether1 | 3,421,752,024 | 2,310,338,890

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:51:11.000 | ether1 | 3,400,993,246 | 2,280,855,212

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:51:01.000 | ether1 | 3,398,541,938 | 2,279,670,896

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:28:52.000 | ether1 | 3,203,175,232 | 2,109,341,780

  | Jul 21, 2021 @ 22:28:37.000 | ether1 | 3,202,014,496 | 2,107,596,187
```

elasticsearch  Timelion Expressions

```
.es(
index=interface-log-*, 
timefield=@timestamp, 
metric=max:netstat.in_octets)
.derivative().scale_interval(1s)
.divide(1048576)
.if(operator="lt", if=0, then=0)
.trim(start=2,end=1)
.lines(width=2, fill=2)
.label("Input rate")
.title("Network traffic (Mbit/s)"),

.es(
index=interface-log-*, 
timefield=@timestamp, 
metric=max:netstat.out_octets)
.derivative().scale_interval(1s)
.divide(1048576)
.if(operator="lt", if=0, then=0)
.multiply(-1)
.trim(start=2,end=1)
.lines(width=2,  fill=2)
.label("Output rate").legend(columns=2, position=nw)
```

elasticsearch query json params

```
GET interface-log-*/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "ifacess": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "ifaces"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "myNetworkInterfaces": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ifaces.name.keyword",
            "size": 1
          },
          "aggs": {
            "myDateHistogram": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "@timestamp",
                "fixed_interval": "10m"
              },
              "aggregations": {
                "intOctets": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "ifaces.in_octets"
                  }
                },
                "intOctetsPerSecond": {
                  "derivative": {
                    "buckets_path": "intOctets",
                    "unit": "1s"
                  }
                },
                "outOctets": {
                  "max": {
                    "field": "ifaces.out_octets"
                  }
                },
                "outOctetsPerSecond": {
                  "derivative": {
                    "buckets_path": "outOctets",
                    "unit": "1s"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```